How to get best result when scanning gold text on a black background
Can anyone suggest best scanner resolution, e.g. .dpi, colour or black and white, output file type, and so on, to effectively scan gold text on a black background?
I am using a standard HP scanner and normally use coloured scans at 300dpi saved as .png files. I have tried a number of options so far gold and black but the results are rather poor as the examples below demonstrate:



An ordinary scanner will not make it because flat shiny gold reflects the light off like a mirror. You get only the edges, surface irregularities and dirt.
Take a photo in well lit environment. Use a tripod, small aperture i.e. big f-number (16 or higher for long field of depth), low DIN sensitivity and long exposure. Place and position the camera so that the gold reflects some neutral grey well lit background. The gold must look gold for the camera. You can check it before triggering a shot. Fix the perspective error in Photoshop. It's possible if you have small aperture.
This all is elementary for photographers, but it can be impossible for a hobbyist who doesn't have the needed equipment nor experience. Because this question has been written you probably need a photographer.

Thanks for the clarification. A pity though ...
